# Total height of html document loaded into TWebBrowser

Tags: html, delphi, browser, scrollbar, twebbrowser

I want to know how to get TOTAL height of html document loaded into TWebBrowser component (Delphi)?

I have found something like this and it is not working:

```
webbrowser.oleobject.document.body.scrollheight
```

I placed it inside OnDocumentComplete event.

I need height because I am calculating PageSize property of ScrollBar (my custom scrollbar - build-in WebBrowser is disabled) which depends on web page height.

Thanks for any feedback, best regards

Comment: please define `"it is not working"`.

Comment: Take a look at my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187441/total-height-of-html-document-loaded-into-twebbrowser?noredirect=1#comment44743633_28187583

The same I get with my version (from my question) of code

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
uses MSHTML;

var
  HtmlElement: IHTMLElement2;
  PageHeight: Integer;

begin
  with MyWebBrowser.ControlInterface do
  begin
    HtmlElement := (Document as IHTMLDocument3).documentElement as IHTMLElement2;
  end;

  PageHeight := HtmlElement.scrollHeight;
end;
```

This is the full height. The `body` element seems to give a bit smaller value (probably thanks to margins):

```
var
  BodyElement: IHTMLElement2;
  PageHeight: Integer;

begin
  with MyWebBrowser.ControlInterface do
  begin
    BodyElement := (Document as IHTMLDocument2).body as IHTMLElement2;
  end;

  PageHeight := BodyElement.scrollHeight;
end;
```

Comment: Strange thing is that is gaves me const value (int) every time I load a new page (I know it has different height because of content), now it gives me integer 1633572 (where browser height is something like 600px, and document is a little bit higher - sth like 650-700px).

I have webbrowser placed on panel, and this panel is placed on the second higher panel2. Don't have any idea why it is not working...

Comment: Hmmm, looks like second option it is working, but as you said height of body is a bit smaller then documentElement, but documentElement gives me wrong height value (const every time).